# TS interface or class

Tags: class, typescript, interface

Might be a silly question, but I just had a debate with a colleague. 
What should be used in TS shape an object, a class or an interface? 
I need to know that a function returns an object of a certain type, what should be used?

```
export class Person{
    name: string;
    lastName: strig;
    dob: Date;

    constructor() {}
}
```

or

```
export interface IPerson{
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
    dob: Date;
}
```

Comment: If you need to add actual behaviour, you will need a class. Otherwise, you might want to share more of your use case as TypeScript has many ways to define a type - so you don't just have `class` or `interface` to choose from - there are literal types, implicit (inferred) types, type aliases...

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to create an Object is to use INTERFACE ! Because you can easily store it as an JSON Object on a database like Firebase... You have no function only properties

Then you could use the CLASS with functions to manage Objects type INTERFACE

The interface

```
export interface IObject {
    id : string,
    name: string,
    description : string
}
```

And then the class

```
import { IObject  } from "../interfaces/iobject";
export class ObjectService {
    myObject = {} as IObject
    constructor() {}
    getDescription(anObject : IObject){ return anObject.description  }
}
```